# How to delete non-contiguous duplicate lines in vi without sorting?

Tags: shell, unix, vi

I know how to remove contiguous duplicates in vi. Either

```
:%!uniq
```

or

```
:g/^\(.*\)$\n\1$/d).
```

But I have a file which has data in a random order and there are some duplicate lines which are scattered all over the file. How do I remove all these duplicates without disturbing the order of lines? The first unique line should be kept and the next(or rest all) duplicate should be removed?

E.g. cat file1

```
Here's looking at you, Kid.
Casablanca 
Here's looking at you, Kid.
Go ahead, make my day. 
Dirty Harry
sleep 5
Go ahead, make my day. 
Yippee-ki-yay
```

Output should be:

```
Here's looking at you, Kid.
Casablanca 
Go ahead, make my day. 
Dirty Harry
sleep 5
Yippee-ki-yay
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one awk liner very handful for this:

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++' file
Here's looking at you, Kid.
Casablanca 
Go ahead, make my day. 
Dirty Harry
sleep 5
Yippee-ki-yay
```

It keeps track of the lines processed in the array `a[]`. Whenever the line comes again, the counter is already positive so that the condition is false and the line is not printed.

If you want to run it in `vim`, do:

```
:%!awk '\!a[$0]++'
        ^^
       you have to escape the ! to be treated properly
```

Comment: Thanks. That's an elegant solution.

Comment: Nice to read that :) I just noticed I have answered many of your questions hehe.

Comment: Yep. You're a quick savior. Thanks.

Comment: The best answer. Thank you!